# Heroku error code H10 App crashed - cannot find error

Tags: heroku

I am getting error from Heroku logs with error code H10.

`2023-07-04T02:03:17.639889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myflix-jwww-ae6ee589cc5f.herokuapp.com request_id=1be38cfd-21e1-400e-9039-8a8850041998 fwd="118.200.92.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

`2023-07-04T02:03:17.893452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myflix-jwww-ae6ee589cc5f.herokuapp.com request_id=90f43e0a-b705-48b9-9942-b108246e486e fwd="118.200.92.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

I tried to update my node/npm etc, and also followed some of fixes. But i still cannot get it fixed. Not sure what's the exact error.

Pls advise.

I will attach my index.js, package.json and also models.js

Not too sure what other information your side would need.

I am currently a student learning on full stack development

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  uuid = require('uuid'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Models = require('./models.js');


const Movies = Models.Movie;
const Users = Models.User;

// //allows Mongoose connect to database to perform CRUD
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cfDB', {
//     useNewUrlParser: true, 
//     useUnifiedTopology: true
// });

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

const {
  check,
  validationResult
} = require('express-validator');

const cors = require('cors');

let allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://testsite.com'];

app.use(cors({
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) { // If a specific origin isn’t found on the list of allowed origins
      let message = 'The CORS policy for this application doesn’t allow access from origin ' + origin;
      return callback(new Error(message), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));


let auth = require('./auth')(app); //import auth.js and ensure Express available in auth file.
const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');

//create write stream
const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'log.txt'), {
  flags: 'a'
});

//set up logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {
  stream: accessLogStream
}));

// in-memory data
// let users = [
//     {
//         id: 1,
//         name: "Kim",
//         favouritesMovies: []
//     },
//     {
//         id: 2,
//         name: "Joe",
//         favouritesMovies: ["movie3"]
//     },
// ];

// let movies = [
//     {
//         "Title": "Movie1",
//         "Description": "enter description of movie1",
//         "Genre": {
//             "Name":"Drama",
//             "Description": "enter description of genre"
//         },
//         "Director": {
//             "Name": "director1",
//             "Bio": "director 1 bio",
//             "Birth": "1969"
//         },
//         "ImageURL": "#",
//         "Featured":false
//     },

//     {
//         "Title": "Movie2",
//         "Description": "enter description of movie 2",
//         "Genre": {
//             "Name":"Thriller",
//             "Description": "enter description of genre"
//         },
//         "Director": {
//             "Name": "director2",
//             "Bio": "director 2 bio",
//             "Birth": "1922"
//         },
//         "ImageURL": "#",
//         "Featured":false
//     },

//     {
//         "Title": "Movie3",
//         "Description": "enter description of movie 3",
//         "Genre": {
//             "Name":"Horror",
//             "Description": "enter description of genre"
//         },
//         "Director": {
//             "Name": "director3",
//             "Bio": "director 3 bio",
//             "Birth": "1933"
//         },
//         "ImageURL": "#",
//         "Featured":false
//     },

//     {
//         "Title": "Movie 4",
//         "Description": "enter description of movie 4",
//         "Genre": {
//             "Name":"Romantic",
//             "Description": "enter description of genre"
//         },
//         "Director": {
//             "Name": "director 4",
//             "Bio": "director 4 bio",
//             "Birth": "1944"
//         },
//         "ImageURL": "#",
//         "Featured":false
//     },

//     {
//         "Title": "Movie 5",
//         "Description": "enter description of movie 5",
//         "Genre": {
//             "Name":"Drama",
//             "Description": "enter description of genre"
//         },
//         "Director": {
//             "Name": "director 5",
//             "Bio": "director 4 bio",
//             "Birth": "1944"
//         },
//         "ImageURL": "#",
//         "Featured":false
//     },


// ];

app.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to myFlix!');
});

app.get('/documentation', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/documentation.html', {
    root: __dirname
  });
});


//READ list of movies
app.get('/movies', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.find()
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(200).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err)
    });
});

//READ - list of users
app.get('/users', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then((users) => {
      res.status(200).json(users);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err)
    });
});


//READ - find movie by title
app.get('/movies/:Title', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      Title: req.params.Title
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

//READ - return genre data by name
app.get('/movies/genre/:genreName', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      'Genre.Name': req.params.genreName
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie.Genre);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

//READ - return director data by name
app.get('/movies/director/:directorName', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Movies.findOne({
      'Director.Name': req.params.directorName
    })
    .then((movie) => {
      res.json(movie.Director);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});


// CREATE - new user register
app.post('/users', [
    check('Username', 'Username is required').isLength({
      min: 5
    }),
    check('Username', 'Username contains non alphanumeric characters - not allowed').isAlphanumeric(),
    check('Password', 'Password is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('Email', 'Invalid Email').isEmail(),
  ],

  passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  }), (req, res) => {
    let hashedPassword = Users.hashPassword(req.body.Password);
    Users.findOne({
        Username: req.body.Username
      })
      .then((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).send(req.body.Username + ' already exists');
        } else {
          Users.create({
              Username: req.body.Username,
              Password: hashedPassword,
              Email: req.body.Email,
              Birthday: req.body.Birthday
            })
            .then((user) => {
              res.status(200).json(user)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
              res.status(500).send('Error: ' + error);
            });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error: ' + error);
      });
  });

// UPDATE - user update username
app.put('/users/:Username', [
    check('Username', 'Username is required').isLength({
      min: 5
    }),
    check('Username', 'Username contains non alphanumeric characters - not allowed').isAlphanumeric()
  ],

  passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  }), async function(req, res) {
    let updatedUser;
    try {
      updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
        Username: req.params.Username
      }, {
        $set: {
          Username: req.body.Username,
          Password: req.body.Password,
          Email: req.body.Email,
          Birthday: req.body.Birthday
        }
      }, {
        new: true
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    }
    return res.json(updatedUser);
  })

// CREATE - user add movie to favourites
app.put('/users/:Username/movies/:MovieID', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), async function(req, res) {
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      Username: req.params.Username
    }, {
      $push: {
        Favorite: req.params.MovieID
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
  }
  return res.json(req.params.MovieID + 'has been added to ' + req.params.Username + ' list of favorite movies');
})

// DELETE - users remove movie from favourites
app.delete('/users/:Username/movies/:MovieID', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), async function(req, res) {
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({
      Username: req.params.Username
    }, {
      $pull: {
        Favorite: req.params.MovieID
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
  }
  return res.json(req.params.MovieID + 'has been removed from ' + req.params.Username + ' list of favorite movies');
})

// DELETE - user deregister
app.delete('/users/:Username', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  Users.findOneAndRemove({
      Username: req.params.Username
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        res.status(400).send(req.params.Username + ' was not found');
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(req.params.Username + ' was deleted');
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

// //error handling 
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
})

//listen req
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "movie_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.16.0",
    "npm": "9.7.2"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

**passport.js**

```js
const passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  Models = require('./models.js'),
  passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');

let Users = Models.User,
  JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy,
  ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;


// .FINDONE() NO LONGER ACCEPT CALLBACK
// passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
//     {
//     usernameField: 'Username',
//     passwordField: 'Password'
//     }, 
// (username, password, callback) => {
//     console.log(username + ' ' + password);
//     Users.findOne({Username: username}, (error, user) => {
//         if (error){
//             console.log(error);
//             return callback(error);
//         }

//         if (!user) {
//             console.log('incorrect username');
//             return callback(null, false, {message: "Incorrect username or password."});
//         }

//         console.log('finished');
//         return callback(null, user);
//     });
// }));

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'Username',
    passwordField: 'Password'
  },
  (username, password, callback) => {
    console.log(username + ' ' + password);
    Users.findOne({
        Username: username
      })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          console.log('incorrect username');
          return callback(null, false, {
            message: "incorrect username or password."
          });
        }

        if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
          console.log('incorrect password');
          return callback(null, false, {
            message: 'Incorrect password'
          });
        }

        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return callback(error);
        }

        console.log('finished');
        return callback(null, user);

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error);
      })
  }
))


passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: 'your_jwt_secret'
}, (jwtPayload, callback) => {
  return Users.findById(jwtPayload._id)
    .then((user) => {
      return callback(null, user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return callback(error)
    });
}));
```